# When did William (Bill) Burke, who discovered the first actual bug, live and die?

Tags: biographical-details, computers

Grace Hopper is frequently credited with finding the first actual bug. In fact, she just popularized the story of how William (Bill) Burke found the bug in the Mark II computer and documented it.

I'm trying to find out when Bill Burke was born and died. Does anyone know?

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, "bug" meaning a fault in a machine dates from 1875 or earlier, long before computers.  And long before Mr Burke.  Mr. Burke's note was just the first time that a bug (fault) was caused by a bug (insect).

Comment: Correct. He found the first actual bug. I've updated the question.